# Post a file with urlFetchApp to a google web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to post any type of file using Google Apps Script to a web app but I am not familiar with doPost.

My code looks like this:

```
function call(){
  var file = getFile('/2.html');   //gets a file from my Google Drive (no point in posting all the code here for that)
  
  var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : {file : file}
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx0aIU_XjOHPXh0P6y2dTMmvGpI6WAuac_Cq5BOGw7nDLRlodT-/exec',options)
  Logger.log(response)
```

This seems to work, although I have read I need to base64 encode a file for it to work properly. That's something I don't really understand.

On the web app side I made a doPost(e) but no matter what I tried to do with 'e' I can't work out what kind of object it is and how to process it. All I want to do really is to save it to Google Drive.

You may be wondering why I am going to these lengths to post the file to disk via a web app when I could save it directly. The reason is I am trying to do the process asynchronously using UrlFetchApp.fetchAll() so I can speed up the process of writing many files to disk at once.

Comment: What did you try  with `e`? What documentation have you referred so far with respect to `e`? If so, Which part or line of the documentation are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Hello @theMaster I have tried:
Utilities.newBlob((e.postData.contents), e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.filename);

I was able to determine e is file=%5BLjava.lang.Object%

I tried JSON.parsing it but I get an error on the first character.

I haven't found any documentation on how to parse a file using doGet or doPost. I have only found documentation on how to work with text.

Comment: If I display  e.parameters then the result is just [object Object]

Comment: have you tired to do JSON.parse(x.getContentText()), and check this link it's something like what you want to do http://googleappscripting.com/json/

Comment: @Doom Thanks for that. I have solved it. You can see the solution in the other thread. I was actually passing an array instead of a file which exacerbated my initial inability to parse e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If variable `file` is of type [`File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getBlob()), Get `Blob` from `File`  and `base64` encode it:

```
  var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(file.getBlob().getBytes())
  };
```

On receiver web -app, Decode it back:

```
const doPost = e => {
  const file = DriveApp.createFile(
    Utilities.newBlob(
      Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(
        e.postData.contents
      )
    )
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TheMaster. I made some modifications to the code because it resulted in an error because a file name was needed. you'll need your own apps script web app url to go here [APPS SCRIPT WEB APP URL]:

```
  const doPost = e => { 
    const file = DriveApp.createFile(
      Utilities.newBlob(
        Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(
          e.parameter.file
        ),e.parameter.contentType,e.parameter.fileName
      )
    )
  }






function sendFile(file){
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var contentType = file.getBlob().getContentType();
  var url = "[APPS SCRIPT WEB APP URL]";
  var payload = {
    fileName: fileName,
    contentType : contentType,
    file: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(file.getBlob().getBytes())
  };
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    payload: payload,
    muteHttpExceptions : true,
  };
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
}
```