# Passing a javascript object to an apps script web app

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, fetch-api

I'm trying to pass javascript objects to my apps script webapp, but I can't figure out how to pass objects that can't be stringified (like a script lock or blob).  For example:

**Client-side gs:**

```
function testEmail() {
  var attachment = DriveApp.getFileById("file id");
  var emailBody = 'email body content';

  //send email
  sendEmailFromClient('sendTo@example.com', "test", emailBody, attachment, 'replyTo@example.com');
}

function sendEmailFromClient(sendTo, title, body, attachments, replyTo) {
  var scriptLock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  if(!scriptLock.tryLock(8000)){
    return;
  }

  var formData = {
    'sendTo': sendTo,
    'title': title,
    'body' : body,
    'attachments': attachments,
    'replyTo' : replyTo,
    'scriptLock' : scriptLock
  };

  var options = {
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': formData
  };
      
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch('web app url', options).getContentText());
}
```

**Web App gs:**

```
function doPost(event) {
  var parameters = event.parameter;
  try {
    var result = Library['sendEmail'].apply(this, [parameters.sendTo, parameters.title, parameters.body, parameters.attachments, parameters.replyTo]);
    parameters.scriptLock.releaseLock();
  } catch (error) {
    Library.troubleshooting(error);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(error);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result);
}
```

**Library gs:**

```
function sendEmail(sendTo, title, body, attachments, replyTo) {
  if (replyTo == undefined) {
    replyTo = gv_accountingEmail;
  }
  if (attachments == undefined) {
    attachments = [];
  }
  var success = false;
    try {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(
        sendTo.valid,
        title,
        "html content only",
        {
          attachments: attachments,
          replyTo: replyTo,
          name: gv_systemBrandName,
          htmlBody: body
        }
      );
      success = true;
    } catch (error) {
      success = error;
    } finally {
      return success;
    }
}
```

The client grabs the file from their drive, and then sends that info to the web app which then accesses the library to complete the action of sending the email.  The web app has special privileges to the library that the client doesn't have which is why I need to send this type of data to it.

If I run the above code from the client, the error that gets logged is "TypeError: parameters.scriptLock.releaseLock is not a function"

If I comment out `// parameters.scriptLock.releaseLock();`and run it again, I get "Exception: Invalid argument: attachments"

If I turn the attachment into a blob via `attachment.getBlob()`, then the email sends successfully, but there is nothing attached.

How do we pass these type of objects to web apps?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> 1. Encode the file first to base-64 web-safe
> 2. Send it in your web app using post request
> 3. Decode the base-64 web-safe to UTF-8 byte array
> 4. Convert it to blob.

### Example:

**Client Side:**

```
function myFunction(){
  var url = "webapp url";
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById("file id")
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  };
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var contentType = file.getBlob().getContentType();
  var formData = {
    fileName: fileName,
    contentType : contentType,
    file: Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(file.getBlob().getBytes())
  };

  var options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'payload' : formData,
    'headers': headers,
  };

  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

**WebApp:**

```
function doPost(e) {
  var file = Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64DecodeWebSafe(e.parameter.file),e.parameter.contentType,e.parameter.fileName)
  Library['sendEmail'].apply(this, [file]);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("test");
}
```

**Library:**

```
function sendEmail(attachments) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(
    "recipient email address here",
    "Test",
    "html content only",
    {
      attachments: [attachments],
    }
  );
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

### Reference:

- [TheMaster answer on Post a file with urlFetchApp to a google web app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63988095)
- [Class Utilities](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)

Comment: Thanks for this method.  I was not aware of it.  However, from what I can tell it seems to only work for files or spreadsheets, and not apps script unique objects like a script lock since they cannot be converted to blob.  Am I wrong?  Is there a way to pass a unique apps script object type to a web app via UrlFetchApp?

Comment: Passing class to a HTTP request is not possible. The request will not recognize the class. I tried it and it just converted the class name to a string.  If scriptLock is very important part of your script, I would suggest to create a doGet() function in the client side, fill it with scriptLock operations that will return a data that HTTP request can read and call it in your Web App.